# C++ Variable won't changed after declare in switch case

Tags: c++

I am still learning C++. I want to write a code that default value is O and X. But user can change it by themselves, while two value cannot be the same and some special symbol. If there are any error, The value will reset to O and X. However, after reset the value in one of the switch case, the variable still contain the error value. Hopefully, I can get some hints from here. Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    string s1 = "O";
    string s2 = "X";
    //User Interface
    cout << "***  Menu***" << endl;
    cout << "[1] " << endl;
    cout << "[2] " << endl;
    cout << "*****************" << endl;

    //Select Option
    string option; //For input
    int o; //For switch statement

    cout << "Option (1 - 2):";
    getline(cin, option);

    switch (o) {
    case 1: {
    } break;
    case 2: {
        cout << "[1] " << endl;
        cout << "[2] " << endl;
        ;
        cout << "Option (1 - 2):";
        string optionstring;
        getline(cin, optionstring);

        switch (optionstring[0]) {
        case '1': {
            break;
        }

        case '2': {
            cout << endl
                 << "current s1 =" << s1 << "Current s2 =" << s2 << endl
                 << endl;
            bool check = true;
            while (check) {
                check = false;
                string change; // For switch
                char c; // For switch statement

                cout << "Do you want to change the value? (Type Y to change or N to return to settings menu)?";

                getline(cin, change);
                if (change.size() > 1)
                    c = 'f'; //Indicates invalid input
                else
                    c = change[0];

                switch (c) {

                case 'Y':
                    cout << endl
                         << "Input new symbol for s1." << endl;

                    cout << "new symbol for s1:" << endl;
                    getline(cin, s1);
                    if (!(s1.size() == 1) || (s1 == "+") || (s1 == "-") || (s1 == "|")) {
                        string s1 = "O";
                        string s2 = "X";
                        cout << endl
                             << "The current setting has been reset to checker symbols‘" << s1 << "’for s1, ‘" << s2 << "’for s2)." << endl
                             << endl;
                        continue;
                    }
                    cout << endl
                         << "current s1 =" << s1;
                    break;
                }
```

When I input "+" into s1, a error message should be showed and the value will be reset to O, the last line code can show that it is successfully reset. But After running the case again, s1 value still contain the error value like"+". Need Some Help!!

Comment: Please provide a [mre], right now you have just copy-pasted your whole code with the problem,

Comment: @AryanParekh, if he is not sure where the problem is or what to do - he still pasted his code which is lots better than others do on here (homework dumping, etc). Perhaps you can try and run his code and give him some advice. Someone with his skill level and being new here is not going to be able to just paste a minimal reproducible example without some more help.

Comment: @David That's why I provided a link on how to make a minimal reproducible example :) It's very likely that once sits down, tries to track the problem he will get the problem without posting it here, I didn't downvote as that would discourage him from posting here, instead, added a comment to let him know that he can do something that will make it a better question.

Comment: I think for a first question it's ok as it is. What you could do is to add the missing closing braces and the proper includes. Aanyway, I see a big bug: the first switch uses `o` which is never initialized or changed anywhere. That means you have undefined behaviour and anything might happen. (Actually I can't even compile it because of this). Fix this bug first.

Comment: Not a solution, but when you declare `int o;`. It's never set anything, so it's value is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your explanation of the problem right, the following should work. In this piece of code you create new temporary variables s1 and s2.

```
if (!(s1.size() == 1) || (s1 == "+") || (s1 == "-") || (s1 == "|")) {
                    string s1 = "O";
                    string s2 = "X";
                    ...
```

Try to avoid declaration of new variables like so:

```
    if (!(s1.size() == 1) || (s1 == "+") || (s1 == "-") || (s1 == "|")) {
                    s1 = "O";
                    s2 = "X";
                    ...
```